# Unable to destroy in memory Core Data Persistence

Tags: swift, core-data

I am trying to delete all data saved inside the Core Data entity once user signs off.

The following is the code that used to generate the Persistence

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
        let viewContext = result.container.viewContext
        do {
            try viewContext.save()
        } catch {
            let nsError = error as NSError
            print("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
        }
        return result
        
    }()

    let container: NSPersistentContainer

    init(inMemory: Bool = false) {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Test")
        if inMemory {
            container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/dev/null")
        }
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                print("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
    }
}
```

This is what I wrote to destroy the persistence and reload the persistence store. I think it is the standard way of doing this:

```
  do{
       print("url is \(container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url!)")
       try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at:container.persistentStoreDescriptions.first!.url!, ofType:"sqlite")
 }catch{
     print("destroy persistence \(error)")
 }

  do{
      try container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: {(nsPersistentStoreDescription, error) in
        guard let error = error else {return}
                
        print("load persistence \(error)")
      })
     }
```

However, it seems the data was never deleted. As I log back in, the previous data still exists.

I am not exactly if the destruction of the persistence store is successful or not, as it doesn't provide as result. I would like to know if the way I am using is indeed the correct way to destroy all the objects created in the entity?

As long as I can see, the `sqlite` file still exists under the directory.

Comment: whats the error's localizedDescription in catch block ?

Comment: No error was displayed at all.

Comment: In my case, I remove the store, but also the file itself: `container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.forEach { aStore in do { try self.container.persistentStoreCoordinator.remove(aStore) if let url = aStore.url { try FileManager.default.removeItem(at: url) } }`. There is a missing catch indeed, but I kept only the main logic

Comment: @Larme and in your case, when you reload the container, the file is regenerated without no problem ?

Comment: I don't have an issue on my code. That's how I do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this other method?

`try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: url, type: .sqlite)`

Difference:

`destroyPersistentStore(at:type:)` and not `destroyPersistentStore(at:ofType:)`

Comment: It only supports ios 15.0+ while my app needs to support ios 14.0+